# What (Unicode) digits are included in \w in Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

For the character class \w does it include all of \d or just [0-9]. Specifically is it including the full Unicode [Nd] character category?

The python docs for \w has the following:

> For Unicode (str) patterns: Matches Unicode word characters; this
>   includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language,
>   as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only
>   [a-zA-Z0-9_] is matched.

But this doesn't specify what is means by "numbers"

Comparing to the python docs for \d:

> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>   Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many other digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is matched.

Here we are explicitly told that it is all of [Nd].

Does \w include the full [Nd] like \d does or just [0-9]

Comment: It's the same as https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum

Comment: `pydoc re` actually seems more clear than the HTML docs.

Comment: Why don't you try it to see if it matches a Unicode digit other than 0-9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is trivial to check yourself:

```
import sys, unicodedata

d = {True: [], False: []}
for i in range(sys.maxunicode + 1): 
    c = chr(i)
    if unicodedata.category(c) == "Nd":
        d[bool(re.match(r"\w", c))].append(c)

matched = set(d[True])
unmatched = set(d[False])
```

Result on my machine (YMMV) is that **all of *Nd* is matched**.

```
>>> sys.version
'3.7.3 (default, Mar 29 2019, 14:24:49) \n[GCC 8.2.0]'
>>> unicodedata.unidata_version
'11.0.0'
>>> len(unmatched)
0
>>> len(matched)
610
>>> print(*sorted(matched))                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩ ۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹ ߀ ߁ ߂ ߃ ߄ ߅ ߆ ߇ ߈ ߉ ० १ २ ३ ४ ५ ६ ७ ८ ९ ০ ১ ২ ৩ ৪ ৫ ৬ ৭ ৮ ৯ ੦ ੧ ੨ ੩ ੪ ੫ ੬ ੭ ੮ ੯ ૦ ૧ ૨ ૩ ૪ ૫ ૬ ૭ ૮ ૯ ୦ ୧ ୨ ୩ ୪ ୫ ୬ ୭ ୮ ୯ ௦ ௧ ௨ ௩ ௪ ௫ ௬ ௭ ௮ ௯ ౦ ౧ ౨ ౩ ౪ ౫ ౬ ౭ ౮ ౯ ೦ ೧ ೨ ೩ ೪ ೫ ೬ ೭ ೮ ೯ ൦ ൧ ൨ ൩ ൪ ൫ ൬ ൭ ൮ ൯ ෦ ෧ ෨ ෩ ෪ ෫ ෬ ෭ ෮ ෯ ๐ ๑ ๒ ๓ ๔ ๕ ๖ ๗ ๘ ๙ ໐ ໑ ໒ ໓ ໔ ໕ ໖ ໗ ໘ ໙ ༠ ༡ ༢ ༣ ༤ ༥ ༦ ༧ ༨ ༩ ၀ ၁ ၂ ၃ ၄ ၅ ၆ ၇ ၈ ၉ ႐ ႑ ႒ ႓ ႔ ႕ ႖ ႗ ႘ ႙ ០ ១ ២ ៣ ៤ ៥ ៦ ៧ ៨ ៩ ᠐ ᠑ ᠒ ᠓ ᠔ ᠕ ᠖ ᠗ ᠘ ᠙ ᥆ ᥇ ᥈ ᥉ ᥊ ᥋ ᥌ ᥍ ᥎ ᥏ ᧐ ᧑ ᧒ ᧓ ᧔ ᧕ ᧖ ᧗ ᧘ ᧙ ᪀ ᪁ ᪂ ᪃ ᪄ ᪅ ᪆ ᪇ ᪈ ᪉ ᪐ ᪑ ᪒ ᪓ ᪔ ᪕ ᪖ ᪗ ᪘ ᪙ ᭐ ᭑ ᭒ ᭓ ᭔ ᭕ ᭖ ᭗ ᭘ ᭙ ᮰ ᮱ ᮲ ᮳ ᮴ ᮵ ᮶ ᮷ ᮸ ᮹ ᱀ ᱁ ᱂ ᱃ ᱄ ᱅ ᱆ ᱇ ᱈ ᱉ ᱐ ᱑ ᱒ ᱓ ᱔ ᱕ ᱖ ᱗ ᱘ ᱙ ꘠ ꘡ ꘢ ꘣ ꘤ ꘥ ꘦ ꘧ ꘨ ꘩ ꣐ ꣑ ꣒ ꣓ ꣔ ꣕ ꣖ ꣗ ꣘ ꣙ ꤀ ꤁ ꤂ ꤃ ꤄ ꤅ ꤆ ꤇ ꤈ ꤉ ꧐ ꧑ ꧒ ꧓ ꧔ ꧕ ꧖ ꧗ ꧘ ꧙ ꧰ ꧱ ꧲ ꧳ ꧴ ꧵ ꧶ ꧷ ꧸ ꧹ ꩐ ꩑ ꩒ ꩓ ꩔ ꩕ ꩖ ꩗ ꩘ ꩙ ꯰ ꯱ ꯲ ꯳ ꯴ ꯵ ꯶ ꯷ ꯸ ꯹ ０ １ ２ ３ ４ ５ ６ ７ ８ ９
```

Comment: Checked and found 610 digits in total.

Answer (score 1):

This may be [relative](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
\d

    For Unicode (str) patterns:
        Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many other digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is matched.
    For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
        Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to [0-9].
```